# How can I get the current view-state id of a Web Flow inside a JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, el, spring-webflow

I use the same jsp for two different view-states in my WebFlow.

- The first view-state is used to add a record.
- The second one is used to edit an already added record (when coming back from an overview-page)

I do not want to duplicate the jsp for the 2 view-states, because 99% of the code would be common.

I would prefer to get the id (name) of the view-state to use it in EL for some basic if / choose logic.

How can I get the id (name) of a view-state in a jsp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to get the name (id) of the current view-state is:

```
${flowRequestContext.currentState.id}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<c:out value="${flowExecutionContext.activeSession.state.id}"/>
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work, the result is just empty. I wonder where flowExecutionContext comes from, it does not seem to exist in my jsp-based views.

Comment: This works fine in my flows. flowExecutionContext is special Spring variable, see http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch03s05.html. You should have it in available in your flows provided the configuration is correct

Comment: After playing with your solution more I found that <c:out value="${flowExecutionContext.activeSession.state.id}" /> works, but only after I enter the flow. When moving to the subsequent view-state, it's empty again. I am investigating more.

Comment: `flowExecutionContext` itself seems to be unset in my JSP as well. Don't understand why